# Apollo useQuery returning undefined several times before returning value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have an app that is getting a user based on an auth token. When I try to access the user data returned by useQuery, I keep getting a "cannot read property of undefined" error. I decided to add a console.log(userData) to see what's happening, and it's calling the query 5 or 6 times with a response of undefined before then calling it and returning the correct object. Can anyone help me with this? It's preventing me from being able to do anything with any of the data I access because of the property of undefined error.

My **Index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql/",
    headers: {
      authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`
    }
  }),
})
cache.writeData({
  data: {
    isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("authToken")
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and my **App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import  gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./App.css";

import Nav from "./components/Navbar";
import DailyWorkout from './components/DailyWorkout'
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  const IS_LOGGED_IN = gql`
    query {
      isLoggedIn @client
    }
  `;

  const ME_QUERY = gql`
    query getUser {
      me {
        username
        id
      }
    }
  `;

  const { data : isLoggedIn } = useQuery(IS_LOGGED_IN);
  const { data : userData, error } = useQuery(ME_QUERY);

  console.log(userData)

  const user = userData === undefined ? "Error" : userData.me

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn.isLoggedIn}
        handleLoginClick={handleLoginClick}
        handleRegisterClick={handleRegisterClick}
      />
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <p>{JSON.stringify(isLoggedIn)}</p>
            <p>{isLoggedIn.isLoggedIn ? `Logged in as ${user.id}`: ''}</p>
            <DailyWorkout user={user} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, per se, but I found a workaround by calling a conditional to check for the data **inside** my component return function.

```
return (
    <>
      <Nav
        isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn.isLoggedIn}
        handleLoginClick={handleLoginClick}
        handleRegisterClick={handleRegisterClick}
      />
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <p>{JSON.stringify(isLoggedIn)}</p>
            <p>{isLoggedIn ? (data ? data.me.username : '') : ''}</p>
            {isLoggedIn ? <DailyWorkout user={data ? data.me : ''}/> : ''}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
```

It's not cute, but it's getting the job done for the time being. Still curious as to the multiple undefined calls, so if anyone has a solution, let me know.